# How do i use a While/For loop to create classes?? (Python/PyQt)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have created the code to create multiple classes with different class names (I.e. Question1, Question2 etc.)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class StartTest(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StartTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        question1 = Question1(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(question1)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(question1)
        question1.proceed.clicked.connect(self.question2)
    def question2(self):
        question2 = Question2(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(question2)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(question2)
i = 0
while i<2:
    class Question+i(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(Question+i, self).__init__(parent)
            question = QtGui.QLabel('What is 5+5?')
            self.proceed = QtGui.QPushButton("Proceed")
            self.Answer = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            layout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
            layout.addRow(question, self.Answer)
            layout2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
            layout2.addLayout(layout)
            layout2.addWidget(self.proceed)
            self.setLayout(layout2)
            print('Question'+i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    User = ''
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = StartTest()
    window.showFullScreen()
    app.exec_()
```

However when I write:

```
i = 0
while i<2:
    class Question+i(QtGui.QWidget):
```

i obtain a syntax error on the `Question+i` part error, which is undertandable. But how would i overcome this whilst still creating multiple classes with different class names???

Comment: Why not just use *instances* of *one* class? I don't see why you need to create separate classes here.

Comment: a somewhat unique instance of [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: Have you considered a list where each item is an instance of your class?

Comment: Is this your way of saying you didn't like my answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23065660/984421) on the same topic?

Comment: ahaha...I considered your answer but didnt really understand how i could implement it! :(

Comment: @HamzahAkhtar. Can you explain what it is you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352781/how-to-set-class-names-dynamically) with answers on how to set class names dynamically.

You need to implement a factory method.  For you it might look like this:

```
def factory(num) :
    BaseClass = QtGui.QWidget
    class NewClass(BaseClass): pass
    NewClass.__name__ = "factory_%s%d" % (BaseClass.__name__,  num)
    return NewClass
```

Comment: The OP is off on a totally incorrect tangent; they do **not** need separate classes as two instances would do fine here.

Comment: Whether or not OP's approach is a wise design is separate from the specific question he/she asked.  A lot of times on SO we get questions where the underlying requirements are not known.

Comment: Sure, but in this case it is clear that the only difference between the classes are *parameters in the `__init__` method*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Makes sense but what if that's only true for this specific example created for SO?

Comment: @Schollii: then the OP should justify the use. From what I can make out the OP is trying to generate some UI *per question*. That's not a usecase for custom classes by a long shot.